# Suprema Proof: $|\sup A-\sup B| \leq \sup|A - B|$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I am trying to prove that $|\sup A(x)-\sup B(x)| \leq \sup|A(x) - B(x)| \quad \forall x$ in some arbitrary set $S$.

It is clear why this is true: the difference between the maximum values of each $A$ and $B$ is less than the maximum of the differences (which is constricted to differences at the same $x$.

I want to use the fact that $\sup A \geq A(x)$ and $\sup B \geq B(x)$, $\forall x \in S$ but I am not sure how.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general you have $$
\sup |A-B| = \max\left[\sup A - \inf B,
\sup B - \inf A\right]
\\ \ge \max\left[\sup A - \sup B,
\sup B - \sup A\right] \ge  \sup A - \sup B
$$

Comment: Is the equality really valid? Take, for example, $A=B$. Then the left hand side is equal to $0$, but the right hand side is not necessarily equal to $0$.

Comment: "Then the left hand side is equal to 0"   no it's not. sup |{0,1} - {0,1}| = 1

Comment: How do you define the difference of two sets?